# Application of the law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

This question is related to my previous post : [The law of large numbers with dependent random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471436/the-law-of-large-numbers-with-dependent-random-variable)

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a random matrix with i.i.d. entries, zero mean and **variance** $1/n$. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ be a random vector which is given by $y = Xz$ where $z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ is another random vector with i.i.d. entries (zero mean), **finite variance**, and independent on $X$.

Let $f(\cdot)$ be some deterministic and continuous function. It is known that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Can we say something regard the convergence of the following series
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(X_i^Ty\right)
$$ 
as $n\to\infty$, and $X_i$ is the $i$th column of the matrix $X$.

EDIT: Ignore.

Comment: "since z is independent of X, we now that (a.s.)" How do we know that, exactly?

Comment: I saw the following lemma: For a sequence of random matrices $A_1,\ldots$ with $A_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (assuming that the matrices have bounded spectral norm a.s.), and a sequence of vectors $x_1,\ldots$ with  $x_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ with i.i.d. entries, zero mean , variance $1/n$ and independent of $A_n$, it holds $x_n^TA_nx_n-(1/n)\text{tr}(A_n)\to0$.

Comment: @Did I added a reference for this claim.

Comment: I guess you should add a "finite variance" condition.

Comment: @leonbloy Finite variance of which random variables?

Comment: If you meant finite variance of $z$ in my original question, then, I agree. But, the question is whether the passages I did in my "thought" are true?

Comment: Of all them ($X$, $z$)

Comment: Yes, you right. I edited the question.