# Strong law of large numbers for function of random vector: can we apply it for a component only?

Tags: probability, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

Consider

- i.i.d. random variables $\{X_1,..., X_n\}$ with well defined first moment
- i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_1,..., Y_n\}$ with well defined first moment

By the strong law of large numbers: 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \rightarrow_{a.s.} E(Y_i) \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

---

Consider these three objects for any function $g: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (take $Y_i$ discrete with support $\mathcal{Y}$ for simplicity)

1) for a given realisation $x$ of $X_k$,  $E(g(X_k, Y_i)| X_k=x)\equiv \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} g(x, y)P(Y_i=y|X_k=x)$ which is a scalar

2) $E(g(X_k, Y_i)| X_k)\equiv \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} g(X_k, y)P(Y_i=y|X_k)$ which is a random variable because $g(X_k,y)$ and $P(Y_i=y|X_k)$ are both functions of the random variable  $X_k$

3) $F(X_k)\equiv\sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}g(X_k, y)\mathbb{P}(Y_i=y)$ which is a random variable because $g(X_k, y)$ is a function of $X_k$.

When $X_k\perp Y_i$, then $(2)=(3)$.

**Question**: **1)** Is it true that $\forall k=1,...,n$
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_k, Y_i) \rightarrow_{a.s.} F(X_k) \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
If yes, under which conditions?

**2)** Is it true that $\forall k=1,...,n$
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_k, Y_i) \rightarrow_{a.s.} E(g(X_k, Y_i)|X_k) \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
If yes, under which conditions?

---

**EDIT**: This question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471436/the-law-of-large-numbers-with-dependent-random-variable) is close to mine and includes also an answer. However it is for $g(X_k, Y_i)=Y_i\times X_k$

Comment: I still don't think I fully understand what you mean by "expectation with respect to $Y_i$ only."  Can you give a precise definition?  Can it be expressed in terms of some conditional expectation?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, see my edited question

Comment: @CGT : The ambiguity mentioned by Nate persists for your use of "$E_{Y_i}[g(X_k,Y_i)]$."  As in my comment to the Adrian answer, it would be more clear if you write expectations without subscripts, as in $E[Z]$ or $E[Z|W]$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I have edited my notation: is it  better now?

Comment: @CGT : Yes the notation makes sense now.  For question 2 the answer is "yes" if $\{Y_i\}$ is independent of $X_k$ (or more generally, if $\{Y_i\}$ are conditionally i.i.d. given $X_k$).  However it is "no" if $g(x,y)=xy$ and $X_i=Y_i$ for all $i$ (which may be what  Adrian wants in his answer, I cannot tell).  In that case $E[X_kY_i|X_k] = X_kE[Y_i]$ if $i \neq k$, but  $E[X_kY_k|X_k]=X_k^2$, so the expression $E[X_kY_i|X_k]$ can change with $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question is deeper. Here I show the answer is "yes" under some general conditions, though I expect the answer is "yes" even for more general conditions than I give.

Your question boils down to this:  Let $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. and let $X$ be a random variable that possibly depends on $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.
Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by: 
$$ f(x) = E[g(x,Y_1)]$$ 
and assume $f(x)$ is finite for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to know if the following is true: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^ng(X, Y_i) = f(X) \quad \mbox{with prob 1} $$

#### Why the question is interesting

The random variable $X$ might have information about one (or even all) of the $Y_i$ variables.  For example, suppose $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. binary equally likely, and $X = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i 2^{-i}$.  Then $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ and from $X$ we can take a binary decimal expansion to reconstruct each $Y_i$ (assuming the probability 0 event of $\{Y_i\}$ having an infinite tail of 1's does not occur).

#### Proof of "yes" when $X$ takes values in a countable set

Suppose $X$ takes values in a finite or countably infinite set $\mathcal{X}$.  For each $x \in \mathcal{X}$ define the event
$$ A_x = \left\{ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x,Y_i) = f(x) \right\} $$
with $f(x)$ defined by $f(x)=E[g(x,Y_1)]$ for each $x \in \mathcal{X}$. Note that $P[A_x]=1$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$ (by the Law of Large Numbers).  Define 
$$ A = \left\{ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i) = f(X)\right\}$$
We want to show that $P[A]=1$.  We have 
\begin{align}
P[A] &= \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}P[A \cap \{X=x\}] \\
&\overset{(a)}{=} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[A_x \cap \{X=x\}] \\
&\overset{(b)}{=} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[X=x] \\
&= 1
\end{align}
where (a) uses the fact that for each $x \in \mathcal{X}$ we have 
$$\{A \cap \{X=x\}\} = \{A_x \cap \{X=x\}\}$$ 
and (b) uses the fact that $P[A_x]=1$ and so $P[A_x\cap \{X=x\}] = P[X=x]$.$\Box$

Comment: The more general case (with $X$ taking values in an uncountably infinite set) likely requires more measure theory tools than I can muster.  I have asked a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756426/law-of-large-numbers-with-one-dependency-frac1n-sum-i-1n-gx-y-i

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is necessary take the function $g(x,y)=xy$, if instead of being independent $X,Y$ are completely dependent ie $X=Y$ we have that on the one hand 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_1, Y_i)=X_1 E(X_1) \rightarrow_{a.s.}  \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}$$
and on the other hand
$$E_{Y}(g(X_1, Y_i))=E(X_1)^2 i\geq 2 .$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not completely sure I understand your answer (see my edit above). Could you reformulate it by dividing in subparts following my questions?

Comment: I do not understand your answer either. The notation is unusual: (i) What is meant by $X=Y$ in terms of $X_i$ and $Y_i$?  (ii) What is meant by $E_Y[\cdot]$ when the expression inside the expectation has both $X_1$ and $Y_i$?  This goes back to the Nate Eldredge comment on ambiguity of "expectation with respect to $Y_i$ only." It would likely be more clear to write expectations without subscripts, such as $E[Z]$ or $E[Z|W]$.

Comment: @CGT Ok, I think we are getting confused for me $X=Y$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are the same stochastic proceses (In this context it is equivalent to $X_i= Y_i$ for all $i$. Respect to the conditional expectation, for me that notation refears for the condtional expectation w.r.t. a sigma algebra, in this case the sigma algebra generated by Y.