# Law of large numbers with one dependency: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables.  Let $X$ be another random variable (possibly dependent on $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$).  Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Assume that $E[g(x,Y_1)]$ is well defined and finite for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know when there 
exists a deterministic function $f$ such that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X, Y_i) = f(X) \quad \mbox{with prob 1} $$
I am particularly interested in the candidate function $f(x) = E[g(x, Y_1)]$.

I have been able to prove the result for the case when $X$ is discrete (see below). I am interested in results and/or counter-examples for more general cases.

---

Context: This question is a refinement of the question here: 
[Strong law of large numbers for function of random vector: can we apply it for a component only?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754659/strong-law-of-large-numbers-for-function-of-random-vector-can-we-apply-it-for-a/2755224#2755224)

In that link, I was able to prove the result always holds for $f(x)=E[g(x,Y_1)]$ when  $X$ takes values in a finite or countably infinite set.

Comment: You can easily show the claim for simple functions, so if you can show that you can interchange limits you could use the fact that every measurable function is the limit of simple functions to prove the claim, so that might be a fairly promising line of attack.

Comment: And you can do that since you can approximate uniformly, so that should work.

Comment: @FranMedjurecan : I don't think it is easy to prove for simple functions $g$.  Actually, I don't think it is true (see my counter-example writeup below).  On the other hand, I can prove for the case $X$ is discrete (regardless of whether or not $g$ is simple), so perhaps approximating $X$ by a discrete variable and imposing some assumptions on $g$ may work.

Answer (score 4):

Fran's comment conjectures it is true for $g$ a simple function. Here is a counter-example.  In fact, it can fail even if $g$ is binary-valued.

---

Let $A$ be a subset of positive integers such that the following limit does not exist: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{i \in A\}} $$ 
where $1_{\{i \in A\}}$ is an indicator function that is $1$ if $i \in A$, and 0 else.

Define $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. and uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$.  Express each $Y_i$ in its unique binary expansion (that does not contain an infinite tail of 1s): 
$$Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} B_{ij}2^{-j} = 0.B_{i1} B_{i2} B_{i3}...$$
Then $(B_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. and equally likely to be 0 or 1. We can arrange these in a 2-d grid:

#### The $(B_{ij})$ grid:

\begin{align}
B_{11} \: B_{12} \: B_{13}  \: B_{14} \quad  \leftrightarrow & \quad  V_1 \: V_3 \: V_6 \: \cdots \\
B_{21} \: B_{22} \: B_{23} \: B_{24} \quad \leftrightarrow & \quad V_2 \: V_5 \: \cdots \\
B_{31} \: B_{32} \: B_{33} \: B_{34} \quad  \leftrightarrow& \quad V_4 \: \cdots
\end{align}
Now use the "diagonal" method to list them as $\{V_1, V_2, V_3, ...\}$ where $$V_1=B_{11}, V_2=B_{21}, V_3=B_{12}, V_4 = B_{31}, V_5 = B_{22}, V_6 = B_{13}, ...$$ 
and so on. Further, any real number $x \in [0,1)$ can be written as a "1-d expansion":
$$x=0.x_1x_2x_3x_4...$$
and this can be rearranged as a "2-d expansion":

#### The 2-d expansion of $x$:

\begin{align}
&x_1 \: x_3 \: x_6 \: \cdots \\\
&x_2 \: x_5 \: \cdots \\
&x_4 \: \cdots
\end{align}
Now define the random variable $X$ as follows: 
$$ X = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} V_k 2^{-k} = 0.V_1 V_2 V_3... = 0.B_{11}B_{21}B_{12}...$$ 
Since $\{V_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is i.i.d. binary and equally likely to be either 0 or 1, $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$.  Yet, given $X$, we obtain information about the entire $\{Y_i\}$ sequence. This is done by forming the 2-d expansion of $X$, as shown in the above picture of the 2-d grid for $(B_{ij})$, and noting that each $Y_i$ value is formed by taking its binary expansion as row $i$ from that grid. Since $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. uniform over $[0,1)$, with probability 1 all $Y_i$ values are different.  So we can define a function $g$ that, given $X$ and $Y_i$, extracts the index $i$.

Specifically define the binary-valued function $g:[0,1)^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as follows:

- Define $g(x,y) = 0$ if the 1-d expansion of $y$ does not appear on any row of the 2-d expansion of $x$, or if it appears on multiple rows of the 2-d expansion of $x$.
- Define $g(x,y) = 1_{\{i \in A\}}$ if the 1-d expansion of $y$ appears on row $i$ of the 2-d expansion of $x$, and if it appears on no rows other than $i$.

Now for any $x\in [0,1)$ we have $E[g(x,Y_1)]=0$ since, with prob 1, the 1-d expansion of $Y_1$ does not appear on any row of the 2-d expansion of $x$.  On the other hand, by construction we know that the 1-d expansion of $Y_i$ is on row $i$ of the 2-d expansion of $X$.  Since all $Y_i$ values are distinct with probability 1, with probability 1 all rows of the 2-d expansion of $X$ are distinct, and so (with probability 1):
$$g(X, Y_i) = 1_{\{i \in A\}} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\} $$
Hence, with probability 1, for all positive integers $n$ we have:
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{i \in A\}} $$
and, by our assumption on the set $A$,  this limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ does not exist!

---

#### (Edit) Measurability of $g$

Notice that the $g$ function is indeed measurable: Fix a positive integer $m$ and fix $b \in \{0,1\}$. Observe that the set of all $x=0.x_1x_2x_3... \in [0,1)$ such that $x_m=b$ is a finite union of intervals. For example, the set of all $x \in [0, 1)$ such that $x_2=1$ is equal to 
$$ [1/4,1/2) \cup [3/4, 1) $$

Fix $j$ as a positive integer, fix a set of indices $m_1, m_2, ..., m_j$, and fix a binary string $(b_1,b_2,..., b_j)$.  Then the set of all $x=0.x_1x_2x_3... \in [0,1)$ such that $x_{m_1}=b_1, x_{m_2}=b_2, ..., x_{m_j}=b_j$ is the intersection of finite unions of intervals and so is itself a finite union of intervals.  For example, the set of all $x \in [0,1)$ such that the first three digits of row 1 in the 2-d expansion of $x$ are "011" is equal to the set of all $x=0.x_1x_2x_3... \in [0,1)$ such that $x_1=0, x_3=1, x_6=1$ (see the picture of the 2-d expansion of $x$ above, where it is clear that $x_1, x_3, x_6$ are the first 3 bits of the first row), and this is a finite union of intervals.

So fix $i,j$ positive integers.  There are $2^j$ binary strings of length $j$, enumerate them and index them by $k \in \{1, 2, ..., 2^j\}$.  Let $B_{ijk}$ be the set of all $(x,y) \in [0,1)^2$ such that the 1-d expansion of $y$ has the first $j$ bits equal to the $k$th binary string, and the row $i$ of the 2-d expansion of $x$ has the first $j$ bits also equal to the $k$th binary string.  The set $B_{ijk}$ is the Cartesion product $C_{ijk}\times D_{ijk}$ where $C_{ijk}$ is a finite union of intervals on the $x$-axis, and $D_{ijk}$ is a single interval of the $y$ axis. So $B_{ijk}$ is a union of rectangles and hence measurable.  Define
$$ B_{ij} = \cup_{k=1}^{2^j} B_{ijk}$$
and note that $B_{ij}$ is measureable. By taking unions, intersections, and complements with the (measurable) $B_{ij}$ sets we can form the set $\{(x,y) \in [0,1)^2 : g(x,y)=1\}$, as shown in the comment below, and so $g$ is measurable.

Comment: Is $g$ measurable?

Comment: @Did : Yes.  Since axiom-of-choice is not used, if $g$ were not measurable, this would be a _too easy_ construction of a non-measurable set.  Formally,  $$ \{(x,y) : g(x,y)=1\} = \cup_{i \in A} [B_i \cap (\cap_{j \in \mathbb{N}, j\neq i} B_j^c)]$$ where $B_i$ is the set of all $(x,y)$ such that the 1-d expansion of $y$ is on the $i$th row of the 2-d expansion of $x$. And $B_i = \cap_{j=1}^{\infty} B_{ij}$ where $B_{ij}$ is the (measurable) set of all $(x,y)$ such that the first $j$ digits in the 1-d expansion of $y$ are the same as the first $j$ digits on row $i$ of the 2-d expansion of $x$.

Comment: Any specific example of $A$ such that the limit in question does not exist?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos : Not all infinite binary strings have a time average.  Take for example one with frames that double:  $$ \underbrace{1}_{1}\underbrace{00}_{2}\underbrace{1111}_{4}\underbrace{00000000}_{8}\underbrace{1111111111111111}_{16}00...$$ and the index set is $$A = \{\underbrace{1}_{1}, \underbrace{4, 5, 6, 7}_{4}, \underbrace{16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}_{16}, ...\}$$
If you sample the time average at the end of 1-frames you get a $\limsup$ of $2/3$.  If you sample at the end of 0-frames you get a $\liminf$ of $1/3$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I had fun constructing and verifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sufficient condition that follows from the discrete case.

---

Let $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be sets such that $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y_1 \in \mathcal{Y}$.  Recall that $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is i.i.d. and $X$ is possibly dependent on $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.  Define $f(x) = E[g(x,Y_1)]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Define *Property ** as follows:

#### Property *:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i) = f(X) \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$

#### Claim 1:

Property * holds whenever $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite or countably infinite set.

Proof: See answer here: 
[Strong law of large numbers for function of random vector: can we apply it for a component only?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754659/strong-law-of-large-numbers-for-function-of-random-vector-can-we-apply-it-for-a)

$\Box$

#### Claim 2:

Property * holds if $g$ satisfies the following “piecewise uniform continuity” property: For each $\epsilon>0$ there is a sequence of disjoint intervals $\{I_i^{(\epsilon)}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, each interval $I_i^{(\epsilon)}$ having a finite size (some intervals possibly being "degenerate" by consisting of a single point),  such that $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i^{(\epsilon)}$ and for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and all $a,b \in I_i^{(\epsilon)}$ we have: 
$$ |g(a, y) - g(b,y)|\leq \epsilon \quad \forall y \in \mathcal{Y} $$

Proof: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Then $X \in \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i^{(\epsilon)}$ and there is a unique index $i(X)$ such that $X \in I_{i(X)}^{(\epsilon)}$.  Define $X_{\epsilon}$ as the *discrete* random variable that is equal to the midpoint of $I_{i(X)}^{(\epsilon)}$.   Then for all realizations of $X, \{Y_i\}$ we have: 
$$ |g(X_{\epsilon}, Y_k) - g(X, Y_k)| \leq \epsilon \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, …\}$$
Since $X_{\epsilon}$ is discrete, by Claim 1 we know
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^ng(X_{\epsilon}, Y_i) = f(X_{\epsilon}) \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$
For all $n$ we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i)-f(X)\right|&\leq \underbrace{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n[g(X,Y_i)-g(X_{\epsilon},Y_i)]\right|}_{\leq \epsilon}  \\
&\quad +\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_{\epsilon},Y_i) - f(X_{\epsilon})\right|\\
&\quad + \underbrace{\left|f(X_{\epsilon})-f(X)\right|}_{\leq \epsilon} 
\end{align}
Taking a limit gives, with probability 1: 
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X,Y_i)-f(X)\right| \leq 2\epsilon $$
The above holds for all $\epsilon>0$, and the result follows. $\Box$

#### Claim 3:

The assumptions of Claim 2 hold whenever $\mathcal{Y}$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Proof: Write $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} [i, i+1]$.  The function $g$ restricted to the compact domain $[i, i+1]\times \mathcal{Y}$ is continuous over this compact domain, and hence uniformly continuous over this compact domain.  Hence, it is uniformly continuous over each interval of the union of disjoint intervals $\cup_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} [i, i+1)$. $\Box$